# How to generate Azure Active Directory (AAD) authentication token for Graph API without interactive login screen for console/native application?

Tags: c#, .net, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

How to generate Azure Active Directory (AAD) authentication token for Graph API without interactive login screen for console/native application?

Details: 
I am using Graph API to read emails with Azure Active Directory (AAD) with ‘’Delegated’’ permissions.

”Application” permission allows a user to read other mailboxes and there is no admin consent for this approach due to security concerns, so I am using ‘’Delegated’’ permissions.

My console/native application is registered to AAD.

Since AAD generates OAuth Authentication token for a specific account using:
1.  Client ID
2.  Tenant ID
3.  Client Secret (Key/password for the application)
4.  Login credentials of a specific account.

I can generate a token using an interactive login screen.

However, I want a mechanism where I can generate AAD token for Graph API (resource) without an interactive login screen within code using C# or.NET

Comment: Where does this app run? Does it run on a trusted server where you control the access to it? If yes, then you can choose either refresh token flow (which must be kickstarted with an interactive auth) or you need to use app permissions.

Comment: @Shravan Venkatapuram Take a look. I hope this would solve your expectation. If is it alright for you then you could mark it as answer to help others. Thanks and happy coding!

Comment: @Shravan Venkatapuram Take a look I have updated my answer. You can set `read the mailbox` dedicated permission by this way. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its seems you are trying to get your token without prompting the sign in page.

Yeah, you can do it using [`client_credentials`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) grant authentication flow within [`C#.Net`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23)

See the following code snippet:

***Access Token Class:***

```cs
 public  class AccessTokenClass
        {
            public string access_token { get; set; }
            public string token_type { get; set; }
            public long expires_in { get; set; }
        }
```

***Token Request Method:***

```cs
private async Task<string> GetYourTokenWithClientCredentialsFlow()
        {
            string tokenUrl = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourTenant/oauth2/token";
            var tokenRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, tokenUrl);

            tokenRequest.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                ["grant_type"] = "client_credentials",
                ["client_id"] = "5f14dea0-5cd---Your_Client_Id----8950-4f646829f870",
                ["client_secret"] = "031Fnwih---Your_Client_Secret----Fx+Ase3V65lpWQ=",
                ["resource"] = "https://graph.microsoft.com" // https://management.azure.com/ Or Any Resource You Want
            });

            dynamic json;
            dynamic token;
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            var tokenResponse = await client.SendAsync(tokenRequest);

            json = await tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccessTokenClass>(json);
            Console.WriteLine("Your Access Token {0}",token.access_token);
            return token;
        }
```

***Generated Token Response:***

Once you have set all of your required credentials you would get the token in response. See the screen shot below:

[image]

> **Note:** This authentication flow would generate token for you without interactive login screen. If you still have any query feel free to share in comment. Thanks and happy coding!

**Update:**

To assign dedicated permission for reading mail. Follow the below steps:

1. Azure active directory
2. App registration
3. Select your app
4. API permissions
5. Add a permission
6. Microsoft graph
7. Delegated permissions
8. Mail
9. Mail.Read (read user mail)
10. Add permission
11. Grant admin consent

**See the screen shot:**

[image]

Comment: @ShravanVenkatapuram No problem. You are welcome :)

Comment: If you have an custom api then what does the startup.cs look like to accept the token from GetYourTokenWithClientCredentialsFlow?  I'm trying to get a web app to call an api registered in the same b2c tenant. services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)

Comment: Better to post new question for your problem, in comment different context cannot be answered well.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me with the below code. I am able to recieve the token now with the user credentials and can read the mailbox.

```
private static async Task<string> GetToken()
    {
        string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}";
        string resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
        string userName = "xxxxxxxxx";
        string password = "xxxxxxx";
        string clientId = "Your Client ID (GUID)";

        UserPasswordCredential userPasswordCredential = new UserPasswordCredential(userName, password);

        AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
        var result = AuthenticationContextIntegratedAuthExtensions.AcquireTokenAsync(authenticationContext, resource, clientId, userPasswordCredential).Result;

        return result.AccessToken;            
    }
```

Comment: [ROPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) is not recommended by Microsoft as it contains your sensitive information at the same time this authentication flow doesn't support `personal account` and `MFA`. For more you could check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc)