# How to get access token without sign-up or sign-in to web app?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I created the b2c user using azure Graph API on Web API because I have to create a user in server-side instead of clients such as web app or mobile app. I did steps in the link(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#CreateLocalAccountUser). My problem is that I can not get the access token that used to access protected Web API. How can I get access token?

Comment: Do you want to acquire an access token on behalf of the user or as the app itself? If the latter, B2C doesn't support it yet, you'd have to get the token from the underlying AAD instead using an app reg there. If on behalf of the user, you can choose from various authentication flows.

Comment: Yes, I want access token on behalf of the user. But in my scenario, it should not necessary to user sign. I have only user object id which created with Graph API and b2c tenant information.  Could you suggest an authentication flow for this problem?

Comment: One option is the resource owner password credentials flow, you'll have to enable that in B2C to use it. In general I don't recommend using it, since you have to handle passwords. But service authentication isn't as easy as it should be in B2C.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have a question about resource owner password credential flow. I can see, the username and password field in the request. How to find the user name and password?  Who is the owner of the username and password, the resource owner or created user?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron, Sorry to late answer, but I did not a time for trying your solution.  I'm trying it now, I will return as soon as possible about your solution. Thank you.

Comment: @xangkcl Sure, Try and let me know whether it is working accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: I tried it, the result is "InvalidAuthenticationToken". Have you any idea about this error?

Comment: Check your token endpoint and resource url, can you please update your question with your request sample that encounter error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you are trying to get access token using [`ROPC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) authentication protocol. Here is the example.

**Code Snippet:**

**Token Class:**

```cs
 public class AccessTokenClass
        {
            public string token_type { get; set; }
            public string expires_in { get; set; }
            public string resource { get; set; }
            public string scope { get; set; }
            public string access_token { get; set; }
            public string refresh_token { get; set; }

        }
```

**Token Method:**

```cs
private async Task<string> GetTokenByROPCFormat()
        {

            string tokenUrl = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourTenantIdOrName/oauth2/token";

            var tokenRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, tokenUrl);

            tokenRequest.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                ["grant_type"] = "password",
                ["client_id"] = "b603c7be-a866--e6921e61f925",
                ["client_secret"] = "Vxf1SluKbgu4PF0Nf3wE5oG",
                ["resource"] = "https://graph.microsoft.com",
                ["username"] = "kironmemb@MyTenant.onmicrosoft.com",
                ["password"] = "@Mypassword"

            });

            dynamic json;
            dynamic results;
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            var tokenResponse = await client.SendAsync(tokenRequest);

            json = await tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccessTokenClass>(json);
            Console.WriteLine("Your Refresh Token=>{0}", results.access_token);



            //  New Block For Accessing Data from API
            HttpClient newClient = new HttpClient();

            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me");

            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", results.access_token);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await newClient.SendAsync(request);

            string output = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return output;




        }
```

> **Note:** Please be informed about following Points:
>   [image]

**client credentials flow:**

In that case you can implement `Client credential grant flow`: You can get full code snippet for this authentication flow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56353142/how-to-generate-azure-active-directory-aad-authentication-token-for-graph-api/56355088#56355088)

If you still have any query feel free to share Thanks and Happy coding!

Answer (score 4):

@Md Farid Uddin Kiron is correct but you can also get an access token without a user for AD B2C.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?view=graph-rest-1.0#4-get-an-access-token

The token request is built up like this:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=535fb089-9ff3-47b6-9bfb-4f1264799865
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
&client_secret=qWgdYAmab0YSkuL1qKv5bPX
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

Example AD B2C:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/contosob2c.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

`client_id` is from your app registration:

[image]

`scope` is `Application ID URI` from `Expose an API` followed by `/.default`. Without `/.default` you will get an error like:

> "error": "invalid_scope", "error_description": "AADSTS1002012: The
> provided value for scope
> https://contosob2c.onmicrosoft.com/11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111
> is not valid. Client credential flows must have a scope value with
> /.default suffixed to the resource identifier (application ID
> URI)...", "error_codes": [
> 1002012
> ],

[image]

If you would like to access something from Microsoft Graph then set `scope` to `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`.

[image]

`client_secret` is from `Certificates & secrets`.

Complete request:

[image]

Comment: I am able to generate the token successfully, but when trying to use it with the https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/Tokens/Pats?api-version=6.1-preview endpoint, I get an error that says "Access Denied: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000 needs the following permission(s) on the resource Subjects to perform this action: Read by public identifier". What permission am I missing?