# Java Graph API scopes issue

Tags: java, azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I am very new with Microsoft Graph API and try to play around with it using the Java SDK by following the tutorials on https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/java with the following code:

```
    String clientId = "clientId";
    String clientSecret ="secret";
    String tenantId = "tenantId";
    String authTenant= "common";
        List<String> scopes= Arrays.asList("openid","offline_access");
   final ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
                .clientId(clientId)
                .clientSecret(clientSecret)
                .tenantId(tenantId)
                .build();

        final TokenCredentialAuthProvider tokenCredentialAuthProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(scopes, clientSecretCredential);


        GraphServiceClient<Request> graphClient =
                GraphServiceClient
                        .builder()
                        .authenticationProvider(tokenCredentialAuthProvider)
                        .buildClient();
        User me = graphClient.me().buildRequest().get();
        System.out.println(me);
```

However, when I tried to run it, it actually prints the following

> Caused by: java.io.IOException:
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalServiceException: AADSTS1002012: The
> provided value for scope openid profile offline_access openid
> offline_access is not valid. Client credential flows must have a scope
> value with /.default suffixed to the resource identifier (application
> ID URI).

What would be the correct scope for running this? Is there any documentation regarding the scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[client_credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow), is where the  app makes service-to-service calls or using application-only permissions.

- So here, there is no user interaction or interface. In that case,
  there is no concept of dynamic consent, as the application must
  statically configure the permissions that it needs .
- You have to add the desired permissions (in this case, email
  ,offline_access, open_id) in the API permissions section of your app
  registration in the Azure portal, AND Using the client credentials flow an admin has to be  granted consent.

[image]

> use a scope in the app, format similar to `{Application ID    URI}/.default` which indicates that the requested scopes are the ones
> that are statically defined in the app object set in the Azure
> portal.

- For example  ,for the Microsoft Graph scope to work,  it should be
  **`https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`** It tells the Microsoft identity
  platform that of all the direct application permissions you have configured for
  your app, the
  endpoint should issue a token for the ones associated with the
  resource you want to use.so that the endpoint should issue
  a token for the ones associated with the resource you want to
  use.

See  [OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#first-case-access-token-request-with-a-shared-secret)

***I  reproduced the scenario in my environment with postman with similar scopes as you gave and got the similar error.***

[image]

***then changed the scope to **`https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`**  and got the token successfully.***

[image]

**References:**

1. [azure - How to get access token without sign-up or sign-in to web
   app? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56393182/how-to-get-access-token-without-sign-up-or-sign-in-to-web-app)
2. [Just what *is* the /.default scope in the Microsoft identity
   platform & Azure AD? - DEV Community](https://dev.to/425show/just-what-is-the-default-scope-in-the-microsoft-identity-platform-azure-ad-2o4d)