# Logging in and retrieving bearer token from AAD

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

My company has a Web API secured with AAD hosted on Azure.

All the endpoints are secured this way and I need to get the access token to be added in the header to hit these endpoints.

I am using a normal console app to hit the API, I have registered the console app in AD and exposed the API to it.

But I cannot find any clear .NET 5 implementations of retrieving the bearer token from az using all the details from the app registration.

Any direction is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate Azure Active Directory (AAD) authentication token for Graph API without interactive login screen for console/native application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56353142/how-to-generate-azure-active-directory-aad-authentication-token-for-graph-api)

Comment: Microsoft Identity Platform uses OAuth2 / Open ID Connect standards.